# Can't retrieve env var value from the next job

Tags: github-actions

This is a test workflow to show how I try to echo the environment variable `TEST_VAR` in two ways:

- In the same job where it has been set (it works!)
- In the next job (it doesn't work, the output is empty string)

```yaml
name: TEST

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  set_env_var:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set env var
        run: echo "TEST_VAR=test_value" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Show env var inside same job
        run: echo $TEST_VAR

  show_env_var:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: set_env_var
    steps:
      - name: Show env var
        run: echo ${{ env.TEST_VAR }}
```

Here it works:

[image: Here it works]

Here I only get an empty string:

[image: Empty string!]

I read GitHub documentation, in particular [this paragraph](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-writing-an-environment-variable-to-github_env), where it states:

> You can make an environment variable available to any subsequent steps
> in a workflow job by defining or updating the environment variable and
> writing this to the GITHUB_ENV environment file. The step that creates
> or updates the environment variable does not have access to the new
> value, but all subsequent steps in a job will have access.

so it seems I can achieve what I want. Where am I failing?

Comment: It's doing exactly what the docs say - it's available to subsequent steps _in a workflow job_. It's not available to _other_ jobs - you need to make and access [job outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs)